# Unity 5 widen view instead of resize

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to keep my game the same size on any screen. I don't want it to resize though. I would a player to  see more of a game field. All game assets should be fixed size, instead player should see more map. How to do this in Unity 5?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to utilize Screen.Width/height? --Unity3d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294885/how-to-utilize-screen-width-height-unity3d)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32362050/294884

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28330740/294884

Comment: this is a very tricky topic.  fortunately there is a huge number of QA on it. in the first instance, become expert in `ScreenToWorldPoint()` ... good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Move the camera backwards, increase the orthographics size of the camera, or increase the FOV, then scale the assets up as a function of distance from the camera.